# Why my readLine is returning null?

Tags: java, null, readline

**My code:**

```
String correr = "msg /SERVER:" + NomePC.replace(" ", "") + " * /TIME:300 \"" + Mensagem + "\"";
    Process textoo = null;
    try {
        textoo = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(correr);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader innTexto = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textoo.getInputStream()));

    String lineTexto=null;

    try {
        lineTexto = innTexto.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (lineTexto != null) {
        System.out.println("Não passou");
    }
    else if (lineTexto == null) {
        System.out.println("A sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso para " + NomePC + " ás: " + dataFormatada);
    }
```

So my readLine is always null and I don't know why. I've printed it out to confirm. When I execute my command in cmd directly I had an answer. So why isn't it reading the line?

[Im trying with an array of strings. Still not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqTHZ.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the command is not currently writing to the error stream?

Comment: yes I am. I've tried everything that I could..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot get the getInputStream from Runtime.getRunTime.exec()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038324/cannot-get-the-getinputstream-from-runtime-getruntime-exec)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is not the way you should specify the command. Your command is made of command arguments, and you must **separate** each!

So build an array of `String`s that contains : `msg`, then `/SERVER:xxxx`, etc. and pass it to `exec`.

---- EDIT

```
String []cmd = new String[THE_RIGHT_NUMBER_OF_ARGS_COMMAND_INCLUDED];
cmd[0] = "msg";
cmd[1] = "/SERVER:xxxx";
cmd[2] = "*";
cmd[3] = "/TIME:300";
...
textoo = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
```

Comment: Are you talking about doing this : String Mensagem = textAreaMsg.getText();
    String NomePC = TxtNomePc.getText();

?? If you don't I'm not understanding you.

Comment: See my EDIT, you must **separate** each argument of the command line into `String`s, and build an array of these strings. If not the entire string is considered as a command but there is no command that is called `msg /SERVER:xxx...`, there is a command named `msg` that takes arguments.

Comment: I've tried it now. Still not working. I'm going to update an image, check it.

Comment: You have several other problems: "*" must be expanded to the files you want, and you shoudn't use `"` inside you last argument, every arg you pass will be received as-is by your command. Test with a simpler command, like `dir` for example...

Comment: I understand what you are saying but my cmd command that I'm trying to use takes " and * so there is nothing I can do. I have to do It like that.... I'm going crazy about this.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the command line interpreter do...  `*` is expanded (by the command line interpreter) before the command is launched, your command don't receive `*` as a parameter. What is the command line you use in your hand-test?

Comment: msg /SERVER:xxxx * /Time:300 "Message". And I need the * because If I don't put it the command doesn't work.

Comment: `*` is a wildcard to represent files of any name, replace this with the files in the directory you are in, and the `"` are just to protect the string, but are not useful here.